# Модификатор static для переменной в классе

Tags: java

Дорого вам вечера товарищи! Сел изучать **Java**, столкнулся с проблемой **"The field cnt cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression"** указывает на строку **public static int cnt        =   0;**

Вот код :

```
public class sc1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class ObjectInTheWorld {
            int id;
            int xpos, ypos, zpos;
            String title;
            //
            public static int cnt       =   0;
            //
            public ObjectInTheWorld() {
                cnt++;
                //
                id                      =   cnt;
            }
        }
        //
        ObjectInTheWorld Sun            =   new ObjectInTheWorld();
        //
        Sun.xpos                        =   10;
        Sun.ypos                        =   15;
        Sun.zpos                        =   20000;
        Sun.title                       =   "The sun";
        //
        System.out.print(Sun.id + " " + Sun.xpos + " " + Sun.ypos + " " + Sun.zpos + " " + Sun.title + "\n");
        //
        class Human extends ObjectInTheWorld {
            String name;
            String sex;
        }
        //
        Human me                        =   new Human();
        //
        me.xpos                         =   1;
        me.ypos                         =   2;
        me.zpos                         =   4;
        me.title                        =   "Human";
        me.name                         =   "Andrey";
        me.sex                          =   "Male";
        //
        System.out.print(me.xpos + " " + me.ypos + " " + me.zpos + " " + me.title + " " + me.name + " " + me.sex);
        //
    }
}
```

Прошу сильно не ругать, всё таки несколько часов назад начал читать и экспериментировать, задача была создать счётчик кол-ва экземпляров класса. **Что я не так сделал?**

В качестве среды разработки использую **Eclipse**.

Comment: Переделайте свой комментарий в ответ, помечу полезным и закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите `ObjectInTheWorld` в отдельный `.java` файл и гуглите на тему `java nested & inner classes`.

Comment: Хорошо, а так нельзя оставить? Мне так не очень удобно раскидывать по нескольким файлам, по крайней мере для экспериментов.

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов Поэтому я и сообщил вам правильный запрос в гугл - вы написали код, который, скорее всего, работает не так, как вы думаете, поскольку вы хотели создать `top-level` класс, а создали `inner` класс в методе.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает, понял разницу)